# Overwrite chrome console log location with custom logging

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, logging, console

When you use `console.log('hi')` in chrome it prints out the location of where the log came from. The problem I have is that I am intercepting the console log right now in chrome like this.

```
this.originalConsoleLog = console.log;

console.log = this.log.bind(this);

function log(message?: any, ...optionalParams: any[]): void {
  this.originalConsoleLog(message, optionalParams);
  this.splunkLogger('LOG', message, optionalParams);
}
```

So in chrome anything that I log now will come from this location which is REALLY annoying trying to figure out where my problems are coming from now.

Here is an example:
[image]

I want that to not say logger.service.ts:36, and instead say desktop.ts:24, or funtime.ts:69 it is not at all helpful in its current form. Maybe if I call it with `this.originalConsoleLog(arguments);` it will ignore my logging function?

Comment: That is probably impossible.

Comment: You might be able to *print out* the location of the caller using a hack, but it wouldn't be a clickable link like in the normal console (and you'd *still* see `logger.service...`)

Comment: It's super hacky, but you can `console.warn` a `new Error` with its stack property set to an arbitrary message. This will log an expandable message, that contains a clickable stacktrace. It doesn't change the file link on the right side, but it's something at least.

Answer (score 0):

So as @slacks said it is "impossible"

The best way that I found out to do this is to put a condition in my logging service to check if you are local and on local don't overwrite logging. Any overwriting of console log just makes the issue from the question.